# Need a Nav-Bar with Sub-Menu, which on scrolling should display their respective text with a fixed width and height

Tags: html, css, typescript, styles, angular5

I need a Nav-Bar with Sub-Menu, which on hovering(hover on sub-menu) should display their respective text with a fixed width and height. For further understanding please see the image below.
[ResultantImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtQ95.png)

In the above image. If we hover over "All Courses". The menu will be visible. While hovering over the items in the menu(Project Management, Big Data..), the information(the part beside the menu) changes. Can anyone share how to achieve it. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you got any example code of what you have tried?

Comment: @SCRATK I have tried this example.                       
    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smngrk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css